# html button desen't change after click on a link , i should refresh the page manully

Tags: arduino

I'm Using Arduino Mega, I developed a page that helps me to control the Arduino

everything working well but the problem when I click on a button the button should change to another button I developed it using if statement and it doesn't change, I used a `<meta>` code to refresh the page but the problem that refresh every time, I just need to refresh the page once I click on the button .

My Arduino Code

```
    /*
 Created by Salvatore Fancello
 Visit: http://progettiarduino.com for more arduino projects

 Arduino Uno with Ethernet Shield Webserver
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
int led1 = 5;          //relay1
int led2 = 6;          //relay2
int led3 = 7;          //relay3
int led4 = 8;          //relay4

byte led_state1;
byte led_state2;
byte led_state3;
byte led_state4;


byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };   // mac address
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 1, 178 };                      // configurate il vostro IP a vostra scelta("192.168.1.89")
byte gateway[] = { 192, 168, 1, 254 };                   // internet access router
byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };                  //subnet mask
EthernetServer server(80);                             //server port     
String readString;

void setup() {


 // Apro la comunicazione seriale:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
  //Imposto i pin come OUTPUT
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);


  // Inizio la comunicazione Ethernet con il server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {



  // Creo una connessione al client
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()) {   
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();

        //Leggo i caratteri da HTTP
        if (readString.length() < 100) {
          //Inserisco i caratteri nella stringa 
          readString += c;
          //Serial.print(c);
         }

         //Se la richiesta HTTP è andata a buon fine
         if (c == '\n') {          
           Serial.println(readString); //scrivi sul monitor seriale per debugging

           client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); //Invio nuova pagina
           client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
           client.println();     
           client.println("<HTML>");
           client.println("<HEAD>");
           client.println("<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />");
           client.println("<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style' content='black-translucent' />");

           client.println("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.progettiarduino.com/uploads/8/1/0/8/81088074/style3.css' />");
           client.println("<TITLE>Welcome To My Project</TITLE>");
           client.println("</HEAD>");
           client.println("<BODY>");
           client.println("<H1>SIAM</H1>");
           client.println("<hr />");
           client.println("<br />");  
           client.println("<H2>You can Trun On or Off The Switchs From The Below Buttons</H2>");
           client.println("<br />");  
          if(led_state1==1) {
         client.println("<a   href=\"/?button1off\"\">Turn Off Port 1</a>");
         }
         else{
           client.println("<a  href=\"/?button1on\"\">Turn On Port 1</a>");      
          }


           client.println("<br />");  
           client.println("<br />");

           if(led_state2==1) {  
           client.println("<a  href=\"/?button2off\"\">Turn Off Port  2</a>");  
           }else{
            client.println("<a href=\"/?button2on\"\">Turn On Port 2</a>");  
            }
           client.println("<br />");   
           client.println("<br />");
          if(led_state3==1) {  
           client.println("<a href=\"/?button3off\"\">Turn Off Port  3</a>");  
           }else{
            client.println("<a href=\"/?button3on\"\">Turn On Port 3</a>");  
            }
           client.println("<br />");   
           client.println("<br />");
            if(led_state4==1) {  
           client.println("<a href=\"/?button4off\"\">Turn Off Port  4</a>");  
           }else{
            client.println("<a href=\"/?button4on\"\">Turn On Port 4</a>");  
            }
           client.println("<br />");   
           client.println("<p>Powered by syam  http://www.syam.info!</p>");  

           client.println("<br />"); 
           client.println("</BODY>");
           client.println("</HTML>");

           delay(1);
           client.stop();
           //Controlli su Arduino: Se è stato premuto il pulsante sul webserver
           if (readString.indexOf("?button1on") >0){
               digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
       led_state1=1;

           }
           if (readString.indexOf("?button1off") >0){
               digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
         led_state1=0;

           }
           if (readString.indexOf("?button2on") >0){
               digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);  
               led_state2=1;
           }
           if (readString.indexOf("?button2off") >0){
               digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
               led_state2=0;
           }
           if (readString.indexOf("?button3on") >0){
               digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);  
               led_state3=1;
           }
           if (readString.indexOf("?button3off") >0){
               digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
               led_state3=0;
           }
           if (readString.indexOf("?button4on") >0){
               digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);  
               led_state4=1;
           }
           if (readString.indexOf("?button4off") >0){
               digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
               led_state4=0;
           }

            //Cancella la stringa una volta letta
            readString="";  

         }
       }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks